# How to read plain text which generated like table view in Java?

Tags: java

I wonder how to read a text file in table view like this in java. The problem is some of data in some column is empty. Is there easy way to understand how to understand it.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  994.0    270    7.0    6.0     93            40     10  280.6  297.1  281.6
  989.0    312    6.2    5.2     93   5.64     42     12         295.9  281.2
  972.0    455    4.8    4.0     95   5.27     48     18  280.2  294.9  281.1
```

Comment: You can read line by line and then parse each line if you know the format and/or delimiter used for columns (in this case it may be a tab `\t`).  Or you can look for some libraries to read CSV-like files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code allows to read the given input data into a list of custom rows.

It uses Java streams and Lombok annotations for brevity.

Input data have been changed slightly to provide empty values in the first and the last columns for demo purposes.

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ParseSpaceSeparated {

    @Getter
    @ToString
    @AllArgsConstructor
    static class MyRow {
        final Double pres;
        final Integer hght;
        final Double temp;
        final Double dwpt;
        final Integer relh;
        final Double mixr;
        final Integer drct;
        final Integer sknt;
        final Double thta;
        final Double thte;
        final Double thtv;

        public MyRow(String[] cols) {
            this(
                parseDouble(cols[0]), parseInt(cols[1]),
                parseDouble(cols[2]), parseDouble(cols[3]),
                parseInt(cols[4]), parseDouble(cols[5]),
                parseInt(cols[6]), parseInt(cols[7]),
                parseDouble(cols[8]), parseDouble(cols[9]), parseDouble(cols[10])
            );
        }
    }

    // helper method to parse integer value
    private static Integer parseInt(String s) {
        if (null == s || s.isBlank()) return null;
        return Integer.valueOf(s);
    }

    // helper method to parse double value
    private static Double parseDouble(String s) {
        if (null == s || s.isBlank()) return null;
        return Double.valueOf(s);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        // prepared stream of string lines on the basis of list; 
        // may be get as a stream of lines using Files.lines(Path.of("filename.data"))

        Stream<String> dataStream = Arrays.asList(
            "----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ",
            "   PRES   HGHT   TEMP   DWPT   RELH   MIXR   DRCT   SKNT   THTA   THTE   THTV ",
            "----------------------------------------------------------------------------- ",
            "           270    7.0    6.0     93            40     10  280.6  297.1  281.6 ",
            "  989.0    312    6.2    5.2     93   5.64     42     12         295.9  281.2 ",
            "  972.0    455    4.8    4.0     95   5.27     48     18  280.2  294.9        "
        ).stream();

        dataStream
            .skip(3) // skip 3-line header 
            .map(line ->
                    // provide better column delimiters
                    line.replaceAll("(\\s{2}(\\d+(\\.\\d+)?|\\s{4,5}))", "$1\\|")
                        .split("\\s*\\|\\s*", -1) // split by | including empty columns
            )
            .map(MyRow::new) // convert to row object
            .collect(Collectors.toList()) // get list of rows
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output (`toString` implementation provided by Lombok):

```
ParseSpaceSeparated.MyRow(pres=null, hght=270, temp=7.0, dwpt=6.0, relh=93, mixr=null, drct=40, sknt=10, thta=280.6, thte=297.1, thtv=281.6)
ParseSpaceSeparated.MyRow(pres=989.0, hght=312, temp=6.2, dwpt=5.2, relh=93, mixr=5.64, drct=42, sknt=12, thta=null, thte=295.9, thtv=281.2)
ParseSpaceSeparated.MyRow(pres=972.0, hght=455, temp=4.8, dwpt=4.0, relh=95, mixr=5.27, drct=48, sknt=18, thta=280.2, thte=294.9, thtv=null)
```

Comment: thank you so much... it save me.. @AlexRudenko